# IdentityServer4: how to add persistent key and deploy in production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

The quickstart sample code uses AddTemporarySigningCredential

> The **AddTemporarySigningCredential** extension creates temporary key
>   material for signing tokens on every start. Again this might be useful
>   to get started, but needs to be replaced by some persistent key
>   material for production scenarios. See the [cryptography](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/crypto.html#refcrypto) docs for more
>   information.

**Is there a step by step guide on how to replace AddTemporarySigningCredential() with my own persistent key, and deploy identityserver in production?**

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options on how to have a "persistent" key. Basically you need to use The `AddSigningCredential()` Extension method to do this. And you will notice that it has an X509Certificate2 argument. The most bare metal way to to deploy this in production is to store the certificate in a cert store and retrieve it from the X509Store. But I would recommend rather using a secret store in the form of Azure Key Vault or Amazon Key Management Service or any other similar cloud offering. Do not deploy the certs as part of your publish artifacts. Rather retrieve your certs from a safe place.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason that you couldn't have the certs in the publish artifacts, assuming they are protected with a *strong* password only known on production?

Answer (score 4):

I still have to do it myself, but according to the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html#refstartupkeymaterial) you should use `AddSigningCredential`. I found an entry at [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/01/23/asp-net-core-authentication-with-identityserver4/) which explains it in the section `Adding IdentityServer4`.